# Django: How to register User to SimpleHistoryAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using Django v1.8

I installed `django-simple-history` and I registered my models.

However I can't register User or Group to `django-simple-history`.

When I'm trying

```
admin.site.register(User, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

I get the error:

```
 The model User is already registered
```

Comment: You might have problems using `SimpleHistoryAdmin` for the `User` model - it doesn't understand how to deal with the password field.

Comment: @Alasdair Can I use any history module for `User` and `Group`?

Comment: The simple history docs suggest you can register user if you use their `register` method. I haven't used django-simple-history before so I haven't tested to see whether it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you get the 'The model  is already registered' error message, you need to unregister it first.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

However, in this case, the django-simple-history docs for [using a third party mode](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#history-for-a-third-party-model) suggest that you should use their `register` method instead of `admin.site.register`.

```
from simple_history import register
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

register(User)
```

Comment: I tried it and even though in my sql workbench the data are stored I can't access it from `/admin` site. I see `NoReverseMatch at /admin/auth/user/3/history/
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/(?P<app_label>eReg|auth)/$']`

Comment: I haven't used django-simple-history before, so I don't know whether it's a bug in your code or the app.

Comment: OK, thank you for your response! It works so it's fine for me. I'll try to fix is in `/admin/User` site.